# How to display blob as image in a view

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I figured out how to show contents of a blob as an image in a table, by changing the column and choosing a mime type and browser transformatin.   Works great!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz197.png)

I can't do it with a view, as you can't change columns.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.